# How can I move repositories section to parent build.gradle config?

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle, build.gradle

My project has a structure:

```
-root project
 -settings.gradle
 -build.gradle
 -moduleA
  -build.gradle
  moduleB
  -build.gradle
```

And I have this config in each module:

```
repositories {
    maven {
        credentials {
            username "username"
            password "password"
        }
        url "http://artifactory..."
    }
}
```

I don't want duplicate this config and I want to move it to parent config. How can I do it?

Now I Have this `build.gradle`(parent):

```
group = 'my.group'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'

ext {
    springBootVersion = '2.1.3.RELEASE'
    cxfVersion = '3.2.7'
    uuidGeneratorVersion = '3.1.5'
    commonLang3Version = '3.7'
    encacheVersion = '2.6.11'
    logstashVersion = '5.2'
}

repositories {
    maven {
        credentials {
            username "username"
            password "password"
        }
        url "http://artifactory...."
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `moduleA` and `moduleB` are subprojects, define it like this in your `build.gradle` :

```
subprojects {
    repositories {
        maven {
            credentials {
                username "username"
                password "password"
            }
            url "http://artifactory...."
        }
    }
}
```